# Build Single JSON string from class properties and dictionary

Tags: c#, json

I have a class Employee

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int ID;
        public string Name;
    }
```

and Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, object> dynamicData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

dynamicData has value as KeyNotFoundException, value pair
for example,
        Country = "US",
        City = "New York"

Now my requirement is need to convert both class properties and dictionary as JSON but key, value pair dictionary must be seperated under a field.

For example, {"ID": 1, "Name": "xxx" , "datafromDictionary" : { "country" : "US", "City" : "New York"}}

How do I convert, can anyone suggest way to achieve this?

Comment: Use the JSON library of your choice (here I used NewtonSoft) and either create separate type to hold the properties or jut construct an anonymous object and serialize it: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { employee.ID, employee.Name, dataFromDictionary = dynamicData });`

Answer (score 2):

Install-Package

> Newtonsoft.Json

OR

> In Visual Studio, Tools menu -> Manage Nuget Package Manager Solution
>   and type “JSON.NET” to search it

and use something like this :

```
string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bsObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Serialize` with `JsonConvert`

```
var dynamicData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dynamicData.Add("Country", "US");
dynamicData.Add("City", "New York");
var emp = new Employee { ID = 1, Name = "xxx" };

var result =  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { ID= emp.ID, Name=emp.Name, dataFromDictionary = dynamicData });
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

OUTPUT

```
{"ID":1,"Name":"xxx","dataFromDictionary":{"Country":"US","City":"New York"}}
```